# Android kernel version name

Tags: android, version, kernel

I have successfully build Gingerbread 2.3.4 for beagleboard xM rev C. Now i want to check Linux kernel version name inside a script which runs after the init.rc. In linux we can find the same using the command uname -r. But it is not found in android kernel. can somebody help me with some sample script to do the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a version file in the /proc directory. Try `cat /proc/version` in a shell and it should display informations about your kernel.

Answer (score 2):

If your phone is rooted and [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en) is installed then `uname -r` should work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can get kernel version using

```
adb shell cat /proc/version
```

or
with the help of

```
System.getProperty("os.version");
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
public static String getKernelVersion() {
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("uname -a");
        InputStream is = null;
        if (p.waitFor() == 0) {
            is = p.getInputStream();
        } else {
            is = p.getErrorStream();
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = br.readLine();
        Log.i("Kernel Version", line);
        br.close();
        return line;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `uname -a` mean?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the AOSP DeviceInfoSettings:
https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/DeviceInfoSettings.java#L378

Answer (score -1):

'uname -r' command also should work

Comment: This command works through busybox. "busybox uname -r"